# Fastest way to move files within remote computer from Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, networking, filesystems

I have files stored in a shared directory on one computer and a Cocoa Application running on another computer on the same LAN.
I want the application to move files within the shared directory.

I’m using `-NSFileManager copyItemAtPath: toPath: error:`. But sometimes it seems extremely slow, regardless of file size. Why would that operation be much longer than doing it directly on the shared directory’s computer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess, I don't know for sure, that `NSFileManager` first downloads the file to copy and then reuploads the downloaded file under a different name. The last thing it does is removing the original file. Of course the downloading and uploading take some time.

The reason for this procedure is that most protocols don't have a 'copy' command. So the client will have to do all the work itself with the explained procedure.

Comment: I was making the same guess but could not believe it. I didn’t know the copy command was uncommon. Is what I’m trying to do uncommon and a sign of bad design?
Is there some server software I could install on the shared directory’s computer, to which I’d send copy requests?

Comment: Writing a small server application with only one command in a language of choice would be not to difficult, at least if you've ever done server-client programming. If not feel free to contact me, it'll only take five minutes.

Comment: Oops, it'll take more than five minutes: security, accounts, etc. Things I'm not experienced with enough myself :D.

Comment: I may go this way, but I wish I’ll find some robust ready-made solution.